# Need guidance for DICOM compression using Pixelmed library

Tags: dicom, compression, gdcm, pixelmed

I am new to DICOM, I have already done compression of DICOM images using GDCM library. But as it creates dependency on Dll files, I am looking for alternatives ways to do it.

I have came across PixelMed library 
Ref. [PixelMed Library Documentation](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/index.html) 
Which has compression classes, I need a proper guidance for DICOM compression with quality factors on Pixel Data of DICOM image.

Also after that how can I decompress the same image using Pixelmed library.

Answer (score 0):

By "creates dependency on Dll files" do you mean that the toolkit includes native libraries ? I doubt you'll find a pure Java DICOM toolkit that is able to write compressed pixel data for all standard transfer syntaxes. There is no maintained pure Java library that writes JPEG-2000 codestream, for instance, AFAIK. You can have a look at [Dimple](http://dicomplugin.com) who can compress into all JPEG transfer syntaxes variants with a control on quality factors, but it relies on a native library too.